# Where is the delete branch option in Gitea's website interface?

Tags: git-branch, gitea, webui

Right now, I'm exploring and getting familiar with the Gitea interface.
I must be blind since I've done this before with GitHub, GitLab, CodeStar, and many more.
I feel crazy for asking this but, where is the delete branch in the website?

[image]

I'm asking because if ever permissions were restricted or process-gates were setup,
I'd like to be able to cleanup after myself of no longer needed testing setups and broken branches.
I've looked around for answers and I've only found:

1. [freeCodeCamp's basic git article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/#:%7E:text=Deleting%20a%20branch%20LOCALLY&text=Delete%20a%20branch%20with%20git%20branch%20%2Dd%20.&text=The%20%2Dd%20option%20will%20delete,branch%20is%20now%20deleted%20locally.) suggesting `git branch -d <branch>`
2. [[GitHub > Issue] On Deleting Branch Completely](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/3867) which isn't my issue
3. [Gitea.Docs](https://docs.gitea.com/search?q=delete) search returning "Delete a package" instead

I understand that there might not be a way, but I haven't found any discussion to reference regarding this.
So I thought I'd ask the SO community to see if we find anything we can share here.
Thanks for reading this!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question was if there is a possibility to do this on the UI. The answer is **yes** (at least with `Version: 1.20.5`).

1. Select branch:

[image: Branchselection]

2. Delete it with the delete button:

[image]

Comment: Good point. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in "[How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/6309)", a `git branch -d <branch>` would only delete the branch locally.
A [`git push --delete <branch>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--d) would delete it on Gitea.

That is what I would use whenever a UI does not readily show the option I need: use command-line and push.

---

That being said, the notion of deleted branch exists since  [Gitea 1.3.0, Q4 2017](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/commit/3ab580c8d6b8a2c063d848f8e3002347c9e5cebb#diff-da76ad2169fb27709c60ab33ac1359ad8bdb97438bbcafe316036d2d43c1a54eR199)

And the button is shown in the branches page, only for branches which are not the default branch.

[image: delete branch].

Comment: I just wanted to see if there was any confirmation on Gitea not having a web-version of this and/or see if this was something I missed on their roadmap ahead or even something they were considering or noticed.

Comment: @Zach I understand. So far, I haven't seen that feature (planned or otherwise) on GitLab side.